# Git (Windows): Newbie: Can't commit new repository ... "did not match any files(s) known to git"

Tags: git, version-control

I just installed Git on Windows XP Pro and I'm trying to apply it to my project.

I'm trying git-ize a legacy directory structure:

```
C:\src>git init
C:\src>git add *.c
C:\src>git commit -m 'initial project version'
error: pathspec 'project' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'version'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?  What does this error mean?

"git status" displays many "new file:" lines so I don't know why it says it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using double quotes for "Initial project version"

Comment: Is this a operating system thing? I had the same issue on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the answer from BloodPhilia worked!

I just wanted to move one of my projects to the GitHub, so I just copied commands from my GitHub repository setup:

```
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/YuriyHorobey/lp.git
git push -u origin master
```

(touch will not work under Windows, just create a README file) and this one had failed:

```
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

I've replaced `'` with `"` and it works!